# Select part of text in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, select

In my SQLite database i have a **nvarchar** column. But when select this column, want to select 30 first character. i test **substr** and **substring** but not true.
how can i do this?
thanks

```
public static DataTable FetchNotesList(int PointId)
            {
                DataTable FetchNotesListDataTable = new DataTable();
                using (SQLiteConnection FetchNotesListConnection = new SQLiteConnection(BLL.SettinClass.IASQLiteConnectionString))
                {
                    FetchNotesListConnection.Open();

                    SQLiteCommand FetchNotesListCommand = new SQLiteCommand();//FetchNotesListConnection.CreateCommand();
                    FetchNotesListCommand.Connection = FetchNotesListConnection;
                    FetchNotesListCommand.CommandText = "SELECT NoteId, SUBSTR(NoteContent,0,10), NoteDate, NoteDateTime FROM PointsNotes WHERE PointsId = @PointId";
                    FetchNotesListCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("PointId", PointId);
                    SQLiteDataAdapter FetchNotesListDataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(FetchNotesListCommand);
                    FetchNotesListDataAdapter.Fill(FetchNotesListDataTable);
                }

                return FetchNotesListDataTable;
            }
```

i use this code. date column show but notecontent don't show in gridex

Comment: can you show the code you tried...?

Answer (score 2):

Well, since you've not posted the code, the basic syntax for getting part of text is:

- **SUBSTR(field_name,start_location)**
- **SUBSTR(field_name,start_location,substring_length )**

So you can do something like:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(field_name,0,30) FROM your_table;
```

See: [Reference](http://sqlite.awardspace.info/syntax/sqlitepg08.htm)